# How to tell if a BJT is PNP or NPN by looking at the circuit?

Tags: bjt

[image]

[image]

Is it possible to tell if a BJT circuit is PNP or NPN simply by looking at the circuit?

For example, for the circuits shown, how can we tell if they're PNP or NPN?

Comment: Yes. Look at the location/direction of the arrow. That is really a question for your textbook or a search engine.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no evidence of effort to research this answer at all.

Comment: A memory aid: emmiter arrow on an NPN is Not Pointing iN

Comment: Another memory aid that has stuck with me for a while: PNP is Pointing iNward Proudly

Comment: Still another memory aid: PNP is Pee iN the Pot. This works really well if you rotate the symbol 90 degrees counter-clockwise thus making the collector the lid.

Comment: your own question from earlier shows which symbol is which: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/424064/bipolar-junction-transistor-problem-where-did-i-go-wrong

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Quite simply, look at the arrow on the leg.

[image]

The arrow will always be on the emitter. Look at where the current flows. The arrow will always follow the current flow.

When the arrow is pointing *away* from the base, it is an NPN. When pointing *towards* the base, it is a PNP.

Answer (score 4):

If the arrow points towards the base it is a PNP, if it points away from the base it is an NPN.

Further, the arrow will typically be on the more positive leg for PNP and negative for NPN.

Comment: Thank you. So would those all be PNP?

Comment: No. Look carefully.

Comment: All but one....

Comment: Oh so c) (the first one) would be NPN because the arrow above the current source is pointing away?

Comment: No.  Look at the direction of the arrow with respect to the BASE of the transistor.

Comment: Oh ok thank you. So d) since the arrow is away from the base.

Comment: @JimmyVailer do you know which part of the circuit represents the actual transistor? If you think you do then it doesn't sound like you do.

Comment: @JimmyVailer That is correct.

Answer (score 2):

This diagram should explain everything

[image]
Any additional questions?

Comment: Your PNP diagram has two emitters.  `Ic` should be labelled "collector".

Comment: @BrianRogers Thx for spotting this silly mistake. I'll fix it.